Stack offset of 4336 exceeded max offset
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct LendingPoolAddBank<'info> {
    #[account(
        but,
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    pub bank_mint: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,

    #[account(init, space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<Bank>(), payer = admin)]
    pub bank: AccountLoader<'info, Bank>,

    /// CHECK: ⋐ ͡⋄ ω ͡⋄ ⋑
    #[account(seeds = [LIQUIDITY_VAULT_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes(), bank.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub liquidity_vault_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        token::mint = bank_mint,
        token::authority = liquidity_vault_authority,
        seeds = [LIQUIDITY_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes(), bank.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub liquidity_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    /// CHECK: ⋐ ͡⋄ ω ͡⋄ ⋑
    #[account(seeds = [INSURANCE_VAULT_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes(), bank.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub insurance_vault_authority: AccountInfo<'info>, 

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        token::mint = bank_mint,
        token::authority = insurance_vault_authority,
        seeds = [INSURANCE_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes(), bank.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub insurance_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

Why have I using Box and zero_copy but still have Stack offset of 4336 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 240 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

The error "Stack offset of 4336 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 240 bytes" means that the stack memory used by your program is too large. This often happens when too many large objects are placed directly in the stack.
Reason:
Even though you used Box and AccountLoader, the structure still ends up being large because:

You have many accounts in the struct.
Each account, even when boxed, adds up in size.

Solution:

Split the Struct: Break down the LendingPoolAddBank struct into smaller structs to reduce the stack size of individual functions.
Use zerocopy: For account structs, ensure you use #[account(zero_copy)] if the data can be safely mapped in this way.
Reevaluate Items: Ensure you really need all items in the same struct.

Key Takeaway
Reduce the number of large objects in a single struct to avoid stack overflow errors. Splitting large structs into smaller ones often solves the problem.

it does work when splitting the struct
